# Place a div next to a specific, dynamic Rails element after jQuery toggles it in

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app (that, I should note, is using Bootstrap's grid system), I have a blog post displayed in a left column. On the right column, I am using a jQuery toggle effect to open a quick form (like where a user could leave a comment).

To activate this form, I am using my jQuery to toggle it in when a paragraph tag is clicked, and that is now working. However, the form, with an id of `#exampleToggle` will post to the very top of the column.

**Question:** What if I want to have the form/exampleToggle not only toggle in but toggle in *next* to the paragraph tag that was clicked?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
            <div id="text"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
    <% end %>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="exampleToggle">
    <%= form_for :cements do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :post %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      </div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".exampleToggle" ).hide();

        $("p").click(function(){
            $(".exampleToggle").toggle();
            });
    });

</script>
```

Of course, if my page was static, this would be reasonably easy. Let's say I had three paragraph tags: I could just create "rows" using the grid system and have the form post in that row when the right id selector is clicked.

Since this is dynamic content, there could be any number of paragaphs from the Rails loop, that solution did not work.

Additionally, I am perfectly fine not using the Bootstrap grid if there is a smarter way to do this. My reasoning now is that I am creating a column space on the right side for the form to be placed -- I just need to find some way to effectively place the `exampleToggle` next to the associated paragraph tag when clicked.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this is heavily dependent upon how you plan to populate these pop out boxes, but the following is an example of how to append using jQuery, and position based on the clicked element via CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).append("<div class='pop-out'>populate this dynamically</div>");
  });
});
```

Then:

```
p {
  position: relative;
}

.pop-out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

If you can create a sample JSFiddle, I can help with any issues from there.

Comment: This looks awesome and works great with updating with that static content (like the pop-out div). Let's say I put the form (that is in the body tags and has a class name .pop-out) inside the .append method -- I notice it doesn't seem to be working. Can you append an element or div from outside of the script? For reference, I mean rewriting like this: ` $(this).append(".pop-out");`

Comment: The content in the pop out will be dynamic, I assume - if you include this in your Rails app and output a div with the class `.pop-out` if the paragraph requires it, then you can just hide the div with CSS and show it using jQuery.

Comment: And yes, you can append from outside this script, however it is heavily dependent upon how you plan to populate those boxes. It might be more appropriate to store the HTML elsewhere, then simply activate and position using jQuery when needed - think along the lines of a modal window.